# how to send data in @html.raw link in Kendo-UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a line of code for a custom button page @html.raw and there I want to send the id to the url I want but when I check the debug data, what comes up is string data, not id = 1 or 2 or 3 .., but instead string #:data.Id# appears

**index.cshtml**

```
columns: [
{
    field: "Name",
    title: "Name",
},
{
    title: "Action",
    width: 200,
    template: `@Html.Raw(@Helper.Link("<i class='fa fa-pencil-alt'></i>", new Dictionary<string, string>{{"url","/FamilyCause/Update"},{"id", "#:data.Id#" } }))`,
},
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using string interpolation like this which should give you your desired output:

The change that i made was instead of using `"#:data.Id#"` we will now be using `$"{data.Id}"`. I hope this helps.

```
columns: [
    {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name",
    },
    {
        title: "Action",
        width: 200,
        template: `@Html.Raw(@Helper.Link("<i class='fa fa-pencil-alt'></i>", new Dictionary<string, string>{{"url","/FamilyCause/Update"},{"id", $"{data.Id}" } }))`,
    },
],
```